# How to hotplug an USB device on Qemu 4.2.0?

Tags: usb, qemu, hotplugging

I have `Qemu 4.2.0` with `Debian Testing Bullseye` and `Kernel 5.4.0` and I need to hotplug and unplug an USB device.

Currently I attach my USB device with

`qemu... -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=x,hostaddr=y`

but when I physically remove the device I can't longer detect it from within the VM (Win7).

So, what should I do to send a plug/unplug usb signal to the virtual machine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do plug/unplug via qemu monitor. see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor.

To hot plug a usb device, type bellow in qemu monitor:

`(qemu) device_add usb-host,hostbus=2,hostport=1.2.2,id=idofyourdevice`

To remove a usb device, type below in qemu monitor:

`(qemu) device_del idofyourdevice`

Comment: thanks for answering, but I couldn't make it work, where did you get `1.2.2`? from `lsusb -t` ?

Comment: With Windows 7 guest didn't work but with Windows 10 did, thanks!

Comment: lsusb -t  so the 1.2.2 is probably two hubs in the path of the device. For devices behind hubs we use the dot notation to represent the tree.

Comment: This answer does not provide any specific example or context information about where to use the command.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham the monitor can be accessed via a unix socket or telnet (maybe some more ways too. To bring up a telnet server you might start qemu with `-monitor telnet:192.168.1.128:5555,server,nowait` or similar. Then when the VM is running you can connect with `telnet 192.168.1.128 5555` and you'll get the qemu monitor prompt.