# How are qemu monitor commands executed from an external script?

Tags: qemu

For example this answer explains how to use qemu monitor to hot-plug a USB device: [how to hotplug USB device on Qemu 4.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762211/how-to-hotplug-usb-device-on-qemu-4-2-0)

But can these qemu monitor commands be executed from a bash script?